# Loop with matrix accumulating values in column

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to make a loop to simplify:

```
dens1ha <- (densidade[1:45,5])
dens10ha <- (densidade[46:90,5])
dens100ha <- (densidade[91:135,5])
densfc <- (densidade[136:180,5])
denscap <- (densidade[181:225,5])
```

I need it stored in a single vector (`x`) and matrix (`mm`) as follows:
values of the matrix density line 1 to line 45, column 5, are stored in column 1 of vector `x` and the matrix `mm`. The line density matrix values 46 to line 90, column 5, are stored in column 2 of vector `x` and the matrix `mm`
and so on.

I tried:

```
x=c()
ii[1]=1
for(i in seq(1, 255, by = 44)) { 
    x[i]=densidade[i:(i+44),5]
    ii=ii+1
    mm = matrix(x,nrow=i,ncol=ii)
}
```

Comment: My understanding is that you want to build a matrix, mm, where the columns are rows 1:45, 46:90, ... 181:225 of the column 5 of the densidade object. On a second read, it looks like you also want to store these as separate vectors which you were naming dens1ha, dens10ha, and so on. If I am misinterpreting this, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description of mm, I think this should do the trick:

```
mm <- matrix(densidade[,5], ncol=5)
```

You could also add names to the columns if this were desirable:

```
colnames(mm) <- c("dens1ha", "dens10ha", "dens100ha", "densfc", "denscap")
```

The goal of storing the vector x is less clear. I suspect that all of your goals may be achieved through extracting from the matrix mm rather than building a separate matrix:

```
# get dens1ha values as a vector
mm[,"dens1ha"]
mm[,1]
```

If you really would like to store these values in a separate, non-matrix structure, the most natural object to use in R is a list:

```
x <- list()
for(i in 1:5) {
  x[[i]] <- densidade[(((i-1)*45)+1):(i*45),5]
}
# name the elements of the list
names(x) <- c("dens1ha", "dens10ha", "dens100ha", "densfc", "denscap")
```

You can extract vectors from this list using either

```
x[["dens1ha"]]
```

or

```
x[[1]]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12168192)

Comment: @LucaDetomi I think you are only half right. I misread the OP also wants these stored as separate vectors, but the mm matrix is pretty clearly (at least to my reading) created by myMat.